# PHP SESSION Conflicts

Tags: php

I have this in my $_SESSION setting script:

```
<?php
//----------------------// Start session----------------------
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
} 
//------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------// Check if Username $_SESSION is set------------------------------------------

if (!$_SESSION['Username']) { // If not current User
header("Location: ./logout.php"); // Session destroy file that leads to session logout landing page
exit();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
?>
```

Now, what I basically do is just check if Username SESSION is set. But, I have come to notice something strange while putting another user through:

If we click the same link at the same time and arrive on the landing page same time, I noticed I can see my Username displayed as his Username and his personal data like email and phone replaced mine in my very own PC! This is really strange to me as we do not even live in the same country or even share same PC.

So, it is obvious I have not secured my SESSION and I have used a lame approach without thinking about security and this can be abused with SESSIONS hijacked.

How do I resolve this conflict? How do I restrict each logged in user to a particular session without conflicts if two or more users access the same resource at the very same time? I need help. I can't sleep since I found this.

---

After reading your responses, I will now show a snippet of the functions.php file which outputs Use data from DB.

First, I get the UserName value from session using:

```
$UserName = $_SESSION['Username'];
```

With this value, I query DB to get more user details:

```
//------------Get User Info -- All user column
$Get_User_Info = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM customers WHERE User='$UserName'");
/************************************************************/
/************************************************************/
$Get_User_Info_row = mysqli_fetch_array($Get_User_Info,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
/************************************************************/
//---- Now list all user rows
$GLOBALS['Skype'] = $Get_User_Info_row['Skype'];
    $GLOBALS['Jabber'] = $Get_User_Info_row['Jabber'];
    $GLOBALS['ICQ'] = $Get_User_Info_row['ICQ'];
    $GLOBALS['Join_Date'] = $Get_User_Info_row['Join_Date'];
    $GLOBALS['Join_Date_Time'] = $Get_User_Info_row['Join_Date_Time'];
    $GLOBALS['Balance'] = number_format($Get_User_Info_row['Balance'],2);
```

The above is what is contained in the functions.php which I require with each page I need protected.

As you can see, I barely see where I have done too much wrong there.

Comment: Sessions are per-user by default.  It sounds like you've done something else wrong outside of the code you're showing us.

Comment: Exactly what @David says. Everybody gets their own session. A cookie is placed in your browser with the session ID, which corresponds to session data on the server. You can enforce the session cookie to be transfered only over HTTPS and allow it only to be read by the browser and not by Javascript, so that hijacking becomes harder. This is done in php.ini. Checkout `session.use_strict_mode`, `session.cookie_httponly` and `session.cookie_secure`.

Comment: In php.ini what values should I set session.use_strict_mode, session.cookie_httponly and session.cookie_secure? And what are the benefits of each setting?

Comment: No, there is nothing you have to configure in php.ini to fix this problem. The problem does not stem from there. There's something else entirely wrong with your code, and you're not showing that code.

Comment: *I noticed I can see my Username displayed* so share with us the code that outputs username. The fragment you've shared does not output anything

Comment: I have edit post to show the content of the functions.php file that pulls user data from db using the username from the current session variable.

Comment: Could there be two users with the same username? Just wondering. It would be better if you search the user info by ID ( storing it in SESSION ) which must be unique

Comment: In my table code:  UNIQUE KEY User (User). No two users are same. It checks for existing user with same ID even before registration can completed.